# SQL - get list of different values from column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table in MySql where I have column type

in this column type are different types

each row in table have type,

how to get list of those values ( not repeating = DISTINCT) ?

example:

```
id    name    type
-------------------
1     apple   fruit
2     onion   vegetable
3     banana  fruit
```

List:

```
fruit
vegetable
```

Idea:

```
SELECT `type` FROM `food` WHERE ...
```

Comment: Do you want distinct value or non repeating value as given below answer is correct for you?

Comment: I need list of all distinct values

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to get distinct Data You Use **DISTINCT**

`SELECT DISTINCT TYPE FROM FOOD`

Comment: User want to non repeating value. You can't give answer as user requirement

Comment: As per my understanding user want non repeating value if he want distinct value then this is so silly question considering his reputation

Comment: @Sadikhasan maybe he got his reputation from some other programming language like javascript ?!

Comment: @northkildonan But I mean if User try to google his question then he can find solution easily

Answer (score 4):

You need to use having clause.

```
  SELECT type FROM food GROUP BY type;
```

Comment: Can you give difference of performance of group by and distinct?

Comment: @JamesVo: You can ommit `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`.

Comment: I was considering this approach, but for that performance with GROUP BY I asked here. I totaly forgot about DISTINCT

Comment: What is meaning by `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;` If there multiple type with same name then what happen?

Comment: Not coming but first @Ing.MichalHudak asking only non repeated value. That is the reason i wrote like this.